# Concatenate single common PDF to directory of PDF files

Tags: command-line, pdf, batch

I use PDFtk, and the PDF Chain gui. Despite reading the [man page](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/) and investing time in a variety of web searches, I can't find the answer to this one -

I have a directory of PDF files, and I want to `cat` a common "cover sheet" PDF file on to each of them. So something like `source1=../coversheet.pdf source2=*.pdf cat out*.pdf`. (I know...)

Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just run it in a loop, once for every pdf in the directory:

```
for f in *pdf; do 
    pdftk A=../coversheet.pdf B="$f" cat A1 B output "$f"_out.pdf;  
done
```

That will create a new file for each pdf with the cover page added. For a file called `foo.pdf`, it will create a new file called `foo.pdf_out.pdf`.

You can make this a bit more sophisticated. To create a file called `foo_out.pdf` use this instead:

```
for f in *pdf; do 
    name=$(basename "$f" .pdf); 
    pdftk A=../coversheet.pdf B="$name".pdf cat A1 B output "$name"_out.pdf; 
done
```

And, to overwrite the files with the new versions, use

```
for f in *pdf; do 
    pdftk A=../coversheet.pdf B="$f" cat A1 B output /tmp/tmp.pdf; 
    mv /tmp/tmp.pdf "$f"
done
```

Comment: The "unsophisticated" first option worked beautifully for me. Many thanks for this! Hope it will help others (like me!), too. ;)